# How to combine 3 standalone applications on java and run parallely with maven in spring

Tags: maven

How to combine 3 standalone applications on java and run parallely with maven in spring.

The three othe standalone applications run on different Db's and I want to make use of these three in my main Standalone app.

What are the required maven settings i need to follow and what are the best spring components i used.

Any kind of answer is appresiable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You mean, use these three standalone applications as dependency in another "main Standalone app"?

Comment: Yes exactly with up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About Maven.

I recomend you to use a Repository Manager (Nexus, Artifactory...). In that repository, you can upload manually your aplications as a jar (I assumed that these three app are not build with Maven, but it could be interesant to migrate them, you should evaluate that).

You have to configure your new app pom.xml and settings.xml to get access to this repository. And then, you can add these dependencies in your new app pom.xml. After that, you can use your applications classes in your new app.

About Spring

Spring Framework, has a lot of things that could help you in your development (like dependency injection, jdbcTemplate and a large etc)

I really recommend you to read the documentation (with the index you can get an idea), and evaluate what things could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply and One more important thing here is the three standalone apps must me on same page for listener point of view i.e for every request the client make the responce must be from the existing object instance of these apps and not creating or hitting new instance for it. So what is the best practice in spring to implement this.

Comment: Can I proceed with CVS repository as I already has that configured..Please advise?

Comment: For the first question, look the dependency injection. The second one, I do not understand, why a CVS repository?